# how can I include a variable ranging from 0 to 1 in a continuous linear model

Tags: regression

Imagine that I am trying to estimate house prices with the following model:

$Y_p=1 + \beta_{surface} * X_{surface} + \beta_{New York}*X_{New York} + \beta_{Boston}*X_{Boston}   $

With $X_{Boston}$ a dummy variable if in Boston

In other words, I assume that the house prices are linearly correlated with surface area, and that there is different mean price in Boston as in New York.

Now I would like to include a house that is between Boston and New York. I could set the both $X_{New York}$ and $X_{Boston}$ to 0.5.

But I am a bit stuck here, as now the predictor is not a dummy anymore but a continuous variable. What should I do to include all houses spread in between New York and Boston and still know the difference in mean price between the two cities?

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like that you only care if the house is either in Boston, in NYC, or between Boston and NYC, just add the extra dummy.

$$Y_P = \beta_{surface}X_{surface} + \beta_{NYC}X_{NYC} + \beta_{Boston}X_{Boston} + \beta_{between}X_{between}$$

where $X_{between}$ is a dummy variable for whether the house is between the two cities.

You need to remove the constant from your regression equation, though. Otherwise, you'll run into a perfect multicollinearity issue (the dummy variable trap).